# Repair USB on ASUS router

Tags: usb, connector, router

I have the following problem:

The USB 3.1 female input on a ASUS RT-AX58U router was mechanically damaged (blue plastic bar.) I had taken it to a repair shop. They gave it back, claiming it's ok now, but it isn't ok.

They soldered on a USB 2 connector (USB modem flashed with lights but router didn't recognize it) then covered everything with superglue. Unfortunately I've moved away and can't get back to them, and I don't have the original USB connector.

I've cleaned everything up, removed their USB 2 and now my plan is to solder a female USB 3 wire extender there, but I can't find the original pinout that is being used on the board.

Here are some photos:

- original router board photo,
- actual state of USB's original place.

I hope it can be familiar to some pros here, can you please advise which USB wires should I solder to which connection plates?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like there are shorts between the data pairs here, so this is unlikely to be repairable.

Comment: You need to glue magnet wire over those ripped out traces and then solder to it. Certainly possible but hard. Check YouTube for videos of it and see if you're up to it.

Answer (score 4):

> Dr. Leonard (Bones) McCoy announces his verdict in a mournful voice: "It's dead, Jim."

[image]

The brown colored areas are where traces used to be on the circuit board.

The copper has been ripped off of the board.  If it were just a trace or two, I'd say try to solder in short jumpers of fine wire.

Given that so many traces are missing and that some of them would have to go under the connector, I think it would be way too much trouble to fix - and that's besides not knowing what pins go where.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes you are right, chances are high that there could be some physical damages on traces. Also there are some remainings of wool which I was using with spirit to clean it up, they can be confused with scratches. Anyways I'd like to give it a try, so if someone can advise the pins sequence I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: It isn't "chances are high that there could be some physical damage on traces."  There are traces and pads ripped completely off of the board.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer and patience for my noob questions.
And may it be an option to attach wires to these places as they seem to be connected to original connector's contacts (see pic by link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HZF9Pj_bVV1N2clKlSPJC-821kqGo5Gn/view?usp=sharing)?